# How can I use Angular JS data inside JavaScript(Google Chart)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, google-visualization

I want to use my angular JS scope data inside my google chart or JavaScript
My angular JS file given below

```
angular.module('reports').controller('ReportInfoCtrl', ['$scope', 'reports', '$rootScope','$location','blockUI',
    function ($scope, reports, $rootScope, $location, blockUI) {
        $scope.getReportDetail = function () {
            blockUI.start();
            reports.getReportInformation().then(function (data) {
                blockUI.stop();
                if (data !== undefined) {
                    $scope.report_details = data;                   
               }
            });
        };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure. You can access your scope variable of controller out  side your angular.

```
var controllerElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="ReportInfoCtrl"]'); // You can use javascript or Jquery to select the controller's div element.
var controllerScope = angular.element(controllerElement).scope(); // Angular provided the interface to access angular's scope
var asd = controllerScope.report_details; // Now you can access all scope variable using 'controllerScope'
```

**Update**

```
angular.module('reports').controller('ReportInfoCtrl', ['$scope', 'reports', '$rootScope','$location','blockUI',
    function ($scope, reports, $rootScope, $location, blockUI) {
        $scope.getReportDetail = function () {
            blockUI.start();
            reports.getReportInformation().then(function (data) {
                blockUI.stop();
                if (data !== undefined) {
                    $scope.report_details = data;                
                }
                return data;   
            });
        };
}]);
```

And in your js file,

```
var asd = controllerScope.getReportDetail();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Abhilash,but I getting 'asd' value as Undefined can you please make sure about that code,one more thing I am just calling 'getReportDetail' function from my html page and it will interact with my service file  through 'getReportInformation()' function

Comment: @did you check your variable `controllerScope`? is this empty?

Comment: '$scope.report_details' only available inside  service calling function

Comment: @nikhilka So now you have the access to your scope from javascript, right? But, you can't access `report_details`?

Comment: Exactly I need to access report_details

Comment: @Nikhilka, Please check the updated answer. Let me know, if it could not work as expected.

Comment: it is not working. 'var asd = controllerScope.getReportDetail();' imaking error in JS

Comment: @nikhilka what is the error? `undefined is not a function` ?

Comment: After that line JS is not getting executed

Comment: @nikhilka, is `reports.getReportInformation()` is a db call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96213/discussion-between-abhilash-p-a-and-nikhil-ka).

Comment: That function will interact with web service ,and web service file handling db

Comment: @nikhilka, could you please check whether the function `getReportDetail()` is executing from our js. Just add some `alert("executing..")` with in your function `getReportDetail()` to confirm the execution.

Comment: No,it's not getting called from our js,but its getting called from my html page when i was not using 'getReportDetail()' in my js

Comment: @Nikhilka where is your js code placed? It should execute only after page loaded.

Comment: Yaa, it's placed as an end portion of my html file

Comment: No,I am using one JS library(Google chart),basically it's an JavaScript file        <script type="text/javascript">
code </script>

Comment: @Nikhilka, I think I am helpless at this moment :(

Comment: It's ok @Abhilash,Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous scope manipulations must occur within a [`$scope.apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to be noticed by angular.